# Return bool from view/ActionLink to method - Asp.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I've to pass a bool inside -> `"@Html.ActionLink(" ", "Like", new { id = Model.Id @*, Pass bool value here *@}".` My model doesn't contain a bool property nor can I add it(database first) or replace the model with a ViewModel. Is it still possible to pass a bool value to my method somehow?

My method Like signature takes a `Guid Id` and a `bool` in parameter.

Can I somehow pass bool:

```
   @Html.ActionLink("Like!", "Like", new { id = Model.Id, @* true bool*@}
   @Html.ActionLink("Disike!", "Like", new { id = Model.Id, @*false bool*@}
```

To:

```
 public ActionResult Like(Guid id, bool getBool) 
        {
            if (getBool == true){    

                return Content("Liked!");

            }else if (getBool == false){    

                return Content("Disiked!");
            }
```

Any idea how to pass a bool value from view to controller?

Comment: `getBool = true`?

Comment: @David Then I always get true, I updated the code( included another button, dislike(returns false)) - both using same method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You pass a bool the same way you pass your model id:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Like!",   "Like", new { id = Model.Id, getBool = true})
@Html.ActionLink("Disike!", "Like", new { id = Model.Id, getBool = false})
```

Ultimately there's nothing special about `Model.Id`.  It's just a `Guid`.  Values passed in don't have to come from anywhere in particular.  Just pass in whatever.

Answer (score 0):

There is not such thing "I can't replace the model with a ViewModel". 
This is the idea of ViewModel, that is, to make a model that will be different from the database model and will fit to the view requirements.

e.g. If you have this model in your database:

```
     public  class Person
    {
       public int PersonID { get; set;}
       public string Name { get; set;}
       public string password { get; set;}
    }
```

and you want to verify the password in the view you don't need to make in your model a propery that verify the password, this you do in the ViewModel class:

```
public class PersonVM :Person
{
       public string verifyPassword { get; set;}
}
```

note, that not allways you'll inherit the origin model in the VM.

After creating the VM, you create a view that the model of that view is your VM that you created for the view. this way you can pass and get any additional information with your view.

Comment: The OP explicitly said he can't replace his model with a viewmodel.

Comment: You're correct, BUT, I tried to explain the correct usage of a VM, I think that the OP missed the point of  VM,